# Do there exist inner product spaces for families of real valued functions other than weighted integrals?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, reference-request, soft-question, inner-products

In transform theory we join linear algebra with analysis by defining scalar products for real valued functions with weighted integrals of products, for example:

$$\langle f,g\rangle_w = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} w(t)f(t)g(t)dt$$

And in multiple dimensions as multivariate integrals:

$$\langle f,g\rangle_w = \int\cdots\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} w(t_1,\cdots,t_k)f(t_1,\cdots,t_k)g(t_1,\cdots,t_k)dt_1 \cdots dt_k$$

To my question, does there exist other ways to define inner products for families of real valued functions?

Comment: It depends on what do you mean by "other" and what do you mean by "integrals". Depending on those, the answer could be "yes" (Sobolev spaces with $p=2$ are examples that involve the integrals of derivatives) or "no, there are no other ways, since every inner product space is contained in a Hilbert and all Hilbert spaces are isomorphic to some $L^2$".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In terms of interesting and useful examples, I think the $L^2$ Sobolev norms are important: one approach to the definition/characterization of $H^k[a,b]$ for interval $[a,b]$ (for example) with non-negative integer $k$, is as the completion of $C^\infty[a,b]$ with respect to the $H^k$ norm (-squared)
$$
|f|^2_{H^k} \;=\; |f|^2_{L^2} + |f'|^2_{L^2} + \ldots + |f^{(k)}|^2_{L^2}
$$
The opposite definition/characterization is as distributions $f$ whose first $k$ derivatives are in $L^2$. It is obviously important to understand that these two characterizations give the same thing. :)

And these are not just definitions for the sake of definitions, but very useful ideas in solving differential equations, and other applications (even in number theory, in my own experience).

As @Mars reasonably commented/inquired: how to see that the $H^k$ norms are not topologically equivalent to some cleverly weighted $L^2$ space? Not responding quite the most directly, but perhaps more conceptually: the Sobolev imbedding/inequality proves that (e.g., on a one-dimensional interval) $H^1$ is contained in $C^o$. We can prove that no weighted $L^2$ space is contained in $C^o$... (though, yes, this is not an entirely typical exercise...)

Comment: Can one show that none of the higher $H^k$ ($k>1$) inner product is "equivalent" to a "weighted" one as mentioned in the question?

Comment: @Mars, ah, good point... edit...

Comment: Thanks, Paul. I like the way you mentioned both definitions of $H^k$. I find that lots of PDE textbooks, $H^k$ is defined via distributions, while the completion of smooth functions seems to be used a lot more in practice. (I may have a wrong impression though.)

Comment: @Mars The fun thing is that it took people quite a while to notice that those two are always the same. The proof was only published in 1964 by Meyers and Serrin in their legendary paper "H=W" (which by the way is less than two pages long).

Answer (score 7):

As pointed out, it depends what you mean by "other" and by "integral". One example that comes up in multivariate polynomial approximation is on the space $H = \mathbb{R}[x_1, x_2, \dots x_n]$ equipped with the inner product $$\langle p, q\rangle  = \bigg(p(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}, \dots \ , \frac{\partial}{\partial x_n} )q \bigg)(0)$$

So apply the $p$ differential operator to $q$ and then evaluate at $0$. An example in two variables is
$$\langle xy, x^2 + xy\rangle = \bigg( \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \frac{\partial}{\partial y} (x^2 + xy)\bigg)\bigg|_{(0,0)} = 1$$

This then just needs to be completed to a Hilbert Space. Upon first glance, it seems like this could be very different from any of the usual Hilbert Spaces one typically encounters. However, the Hilbert completion of this is the space of power series in $(x_1, \dots , x_n)$ with square summable coefficients.  As a Hilbert Space, it's isomorphic to $l^2(\mathbb{N})$.

Comment: This sounds cool, but I don't quite get the meaning of partial differentiation with respect to variables as function arguments of $p$. Or is it $\nabla$ working on $q$?

Comment: @mathreadler Since $p$ is a polynomial, you can make up a definition like: $\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\right)^{2} q = \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \frac{\partial q}{\partial x}$, $\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right)q = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\frac{\partial q}{\partial y}$, etc.

Comment: A polynomial can be given as associated differential operator. For instance the polymomial $2x^2 + y^2$ has has it's associated operator $2\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2} $ or $xy$ has $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\frac{\partial}{\partial y} $   Here the inner product is  defined by having the associated differential operator of $p$ act on $q$ and then evaluate the result at $0$.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't specify real valued functions further, there is also a really strange example: $l^2(\mathbb{R})$, the space of functions $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ for which $\sum_{x\in\mathbb{R}} |f(x)|^2 < \infty$ with the scalar product

$$\langle f,g\rangle_{l^2(\mathbb{R})} := \sum_{x\in\mathbb{R}} f(x)g(x)$$

is a well defined Hilbert-space. (Neither the sums nor the small $l$ are a typo and you have to think a bit about well-definedness)

In particular the space only consists of functions $f$ such that $\{x\in \mathbb{R}: f(x) \neq 0\}$ is countable, which means that $f=0$ almost everywhere. It is also not separable and as a result not isomorphic to $l^2(\mathbb{N})$ and thus to any of the other examples (which are all isomorphic to each other).

Comment: Note that this is an $L^2$ space with the counting measure instead of the Lebesgue measure, so it can be viewed as an integral.